# Can not find close location in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this  Document in my MongoDB:

```
{
"startPoint" : {
    "longitude" : 32.0483346,
    "latitude" : 34.7617836
},
"endPoint" : {
    "longitude" : 32.156827,
    "latitude" : 34.89211
},
```

}

I need to see if a location is in 5000 meters from the start location, My code is:

```
            var longitude = parseFloat(item.startPoint.longitude);
            var latitude = parseFloat(item.startPoint.latitude);

            db.collection(collectionNames.RIDES, function(err, collection) {
                collection.find({startPoint:
                {$near:
                        {$geometry:
                            {type : "Point",
                                coordinates:[longitude ,latitude]}},
                                $maxDistance : maxDistance
                                }
                        }
                    )
```

From some reason this is not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In this URL you can fin information about `$near` in MongoDB 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near.

Your query should be:

```
db.YourCollection.find( { startPoint : 
                         { $near :
                           { $geometry :
                               { type : "Point" ,
                                 coordinates: [ longitude, latitude ] } },
                             $maxDistance : 5000
                } } )
```

So, maybe your query is not getting the `$maxDistance` value. According to the documentation

> "The optional $maxDistance operator limits a $near query to return
>   only those documents that fall within a maximum distance of a point.
>   If you query for a GeoJSON point, specify $maxDistance in meters. If
>   you query for legacy coordinate pairs, specify $maxDistance in
>   radians."

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what is the difference in the query you wrote.
in- $maxDistance : maxDistance
maxDistance is a parameter that have the value of 5000.

Comment: Do you try to pass the value directly, without the parameter? Your query is correct. What is the result of your query? Maybe you don't have data for this query

Comment: Yes I have try running it in mongo without the parameter.
It returns all the data I have not only the ones that are 5000 meters from there.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the coordinate's format. For this I added the urls, because you are using the correct query